# Incoherent behaviour of python regarding bool and set

Tags: python, set, boolean

I noticed a strange behaviour of python3 regarding set and boolean values.

```
>>{True}
>>type({True})
<class 'set'>
```

However,

```
>>set(True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable
```

I'm quite puzzled here.

Comment: The first is a literal `set` with one element of type `bool`. The second is trying to cast a `bool` to a `set` - which isn't possible.

Comment: There is a good clue in *'bool' object is not iterable*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set constructor needs an iterable, use `set((True,))` or `set([True])`, you're trying to cast a `bool` into a `set` which is throwing that error.
Read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) for more info.